# Setting frame if in landscape not functioning iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, cydia-substrate, logos

I am writing a tweak to change the size of the control center.

I am trying to set the frame depending on the orientation.

This is the code:

```
%hook SBControlCenterContainerView
-(void)layoutSubviews{
%orig;
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation ]== UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, (screenBounds.size.width - 20), 427);
} else {
self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 227, screenBounds.size.width - 20, 427);
}
}
%end
```

But the frame does not change if I switch to landscape mode. It only sets the frame with what is set for the else statement. What am I doing wrong and it there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation...`.   This is the hardware orientation and does not always reflect the true state of the user interface.   Use `UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` instead.

Lastly, you should really be using Auto Layout instead of manipulating frames directly like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the center of SBControlCenterContainerView in it's parent, hope this helps and good luck.

```
// In Parent UIViewController
self.sBControlCenterContainerView.center = self.view.center;
```